# Explain how the flags work in conditional jumps in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, conditional-statements, eflags

I'm new to Assembly language, I'm reading `Assembly Language Programming By Ytha Yu, Charles Marut`

Anyway, I'm in `Chapter 6` and I can't figure out the case of the flags which the processor uses to do conditional jumps. I know what the flags basically do, for example, I know that Overflow flag sets or resets if any overflow occurs or doesn't in the last instruction. But I can't figure out how they play into the conditions of the jumps.

[image: Signed Conditional Jumps]
[image: Unsigned Conditional Jumps]

> It would be really helpful if anyone helped me understand the uses of flag registers to implement conditional jumps.

Comment: the jump is taken if the corresponding flag is set/not set. Otherwise you move on.

Comment: @qwr I want to know why those flags are working, e.g. I know `JNE` requires `ZF<>0`, cause `CMP AX,BX` would be zero if `AX` and `BX` are equal. What about the others?

Comment: @klaus For each flag, the conditions are listed in the right columns.  If you want to understand why the flags are set the way they are in the give situations, I recommend you to try some examples on a sheet of paper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly JLE jmp instruction example](//stackoverflow.com/q/4557279)  also [Assembly je, jns, jle which register does it use?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38003988) has a useful answer, but the question is a confusing misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is: there are some operations that set or clear individual flags - arithmetic, bitwise, comparisons. You are then free to perform conditional jumps based on the result of those operations.

Let's consider the most basic case - jump if one variable is greater than another. Assuming the variables are in the general purpose registers, and the code is 32-bit, this would go:

```
cmp eax, ebx
ja AOverB
```

Now, what does that do? The CMP line calculates the value `EAX-EBX`, doesn't store it anywhere, but sets the flags. Specifically, the Zero flag is set if the result of the subtraction is zero (i. e. `EAX-EBX=0`, i. e. `EAX=EBX`), and cleared if it's not. The Carry flag is set if `EAX<EBX` (i. e. subtracting them would require a borrow). So the JA command goes: take the jump if the Zero flag is not set and the Carry flag is not set either (that is, neither `EAX=EBX` nor `EAX<EBX`). By obvious math, if neither of those flags is set, that means `EAX>EBX`.

Did that help? Do you get the concepts of carry and borrow, and their close relative overflow?